# Prevent Navigator.push if user press back button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-onpressed

In my app I need execute code before call `Navigator.push`. But problem is if user press back button before code is execute then there is error:

> E/flutter ( 8415): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is
>   unsafe. E/flutter ( 8415): At this point the state of the widget's
>   element tree is no longer stable. E/flutter ( 8415): To safely refer
>   to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to
>   the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
>   didChangeDependencies() method.

Issue is code is still execute and `Navigator.push` is call even if user press back button (in `Widget2`).

Here is mwe:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Widget1(),
    );
  }
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Widget2(),
                ));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
//      Press back button before Future complete
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
        await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Widget3(),
            ));
      },
    ));
  }
}

class Widget3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text('Widget 3'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do, depending on what you want exactly:

- **To replace current view by new one**, preventing your users from navigating back to the previous page, use `Navigator.pushReplacement(...)`
- **To show a back button in the app bar, but prevent users from going back**, wrap your `Scaffold` with [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html), and make the `onWillPop` property return a `Future.value(false)`.
- **To simply hide the back button button**, go for: `AppBar(...,automaticallyImplyLeading: false,...)`. Users will still be able to go back by pressing the back button in Android, or the swipe gesture in iOS.

Comment: I not want prevent user press back button. I want prevent call to `Navigator.push`  in `Widget2` when user press back button after press `RaisedButton`

Comment: I see, I am sorry, I did not understand your question in the first place. I guess what you can try to do is make your `Widget2` stateful, define a boolean variable `didPressBack` that is defaulting to `false`, and wrap your `Widget2`'s Scaffold in a `WillPopScope` widget, that will detect if the user presses the back button. In the `onWillPop` function, change the `didPressBack` variable to `true`, and then, in the `onPress` function of `Widget2`, navigate only if `didPressBack` is `false`.